# Sqoop : Truncate SQL Server table before exporting data from Hadoop

Tags: sql-server, hadoop, sqoop

We are using Sqoop to export data from the hive to SQL Server. The new data is always appended to the existing data in SQL Server.

Is it possible to truncate the SQL Server table via Sqoop before starting the export?

Comment: I know nothing about Squoop, but it seems to be a command-line tool so presumably you could wrap it in a script that connects to SQL Server and truncates the table before the import runs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sqoop is not a general query tool, the "eval" functionality is provided only for evaluation purpose and should not be used in production mode. You can always put together simple java code that will do that in a way that is best for your use case.

Comment: You'll need to do some extra work to make it atomic though. Assuming you don't want to truncate the table and then find out that your sqoop export failed for whatever reason and you're left with an empty table.

Answer (score 8):

You can use [sqoop eval](http://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.0-incubating/SqoopUserGuide.html#id1772462) to execute arbitrary SQL on the database. This will allow you to truncate the table without "leaving" Sqoop. For example:

```
sqoop eval --connect 'jdbc:sqlserver://1.1.1.1;database=SomeDatabase;username=someUser;password=somePassword' --query "TRUNCATE TABLE some_table"

sqoop export --connect 'jdbc:sqlserver://1.1.1.1;database=SomeDatabase;username=someUser;password=somePassword' --export-dir /path/to/someTable/on/HDFS --table some_table --fields-terminated-by \001
```

`--fields-terminated-by \001` assumes that the Hive table is using the default delimiters.

Answer (score 0):

There is a feature request to implement sqoop --truncate option
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SQOOP-1313

Please vote up on that JIRA page if you're interested.